# Vue setCustomValidity with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, validation, input

I'm currently trying to change the default invalid text from form inputs using the code below. The way I'm trying to do it works if the text is static but in my case, the text must be dynamic so I have to put in some sort of prop/data value instead. This is because users will have the ability to toggle between English and Chinese text. I've tried using `@invalid` and `:oninvalid` but those don't seem to work. Would anyone be able to help me get through this issue?

```
<input
  ref="firstInput1"
  type="email"
  v-model="email"
  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('custom text on invalid')"
  onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
  :placeholder="Email"
  required
/>
```

oninvalid and onchange are the two key components to making this work. Hopefully we can find out how to do this with dynamic text.

Answer (score 0):

For change event in Vue input you should use @change (not onchange)

And I think this sample can help you to set vue validation on email

```
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div :class="['input-group', isEmailValid()]">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></span>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" v-model="email" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: '',
    reg: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/
  },
  methods: {
    isEmailValid: function() {
      return (this.email == "")? "" : (this.reg.test(this.email)) ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm looking for the form input attribute "required" to do the validation for me. I'm simply looking to change the popup text when a form is invalid. @change does not work with setCustomValidity